# What is the format of IDs returned by the Google's Instance ID?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

Google recently introduced [Instance ID](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/). This lib has come up because they now recommend using it to retrieve your registration token for [Google Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/registration).

On the server, we validate the tokens input. The Instance ID tokens are a different format from before - they have are a different length and have colons in them now.

I can't seem to find any place where the format of Instance IDs are defined, for validation purposes. Does anyone know where to find the format?

Comment: what about trying to send a message ? if it is wrong you would get it in the response (not registered or wrong id)  ... you can also use such message on the device to get know that the registration with your server is finished

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Instance IDs are purposefully opaque. However, if you'd like to do server side verification (and also use features such as determining when the device was last online), you can use the [Instance ID Server API](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server)

Comment: What are their max length? This is asked by my backend coworker